# Python / GPyOpt: Optimizing only one argument

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, hyperparameters, gpyopt

I´m currently trying to find the minimum of some function `f(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...)` via Gaussian optimization using the [GPyOpt](https://github.com/SheffieldML/GPyOpt) module. While `f(...)` takes many input arguments, I only want to optimize a single one of them. How do you do that?

My current "solution" is to put `f(...)` in a dummy class and specify the not-to-be-optimized arguments while initializing it. While this is arguably the most pythonesque way of solving this problem, it`s also way more complicated than it has any right to be.

Short working example for a function `f(x, y, method)` with fixed `y` (a numeric) and `method` (a string) while optimizing `x`:

```
import GPyOpt
import numpy as np

# dummy class
class TarFun(object):
    # fix y while initializing the object
    def __init__(self, y, method):
        self.y = y
        self.method = method
    # actual function to be minimized
    def f(self, x):
        if self.method == 'sin':
            return np.sin(x-self.y)
        elif self.method == 'cos':
            return np.cos(x-self.y)

# create TarFun object with y fixed to 2 and use 'sin' method
tarFunObj = TarFun(y=2, method='sin')
# describe properties of x
space = [{'name':'x', 'type': 'continuous', 'domain': (-5,5)}]
# create GPyOpt object that will only optimize x
optObj = GPyOpt.methods.BayesianOptimization(tarFunObj.f, space)
```

There definitely has to be a simpler way. But all the examples I found optimize all arguments and I couldn't figure it out reading the code on github (I though i would find the information in [GPyOpt.core.task.space](https://github.com/SheffieldML/GPyOpt/blob/master/GPyOpt/core/task/space.py) , but had no luck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPyOpt supports this natively with context. You describe the whole domain of your function, and then fix values of some of the variables with a context dictionary when calling optimization routine. API looks like that:

```
myBopt.run_optimization(..., context={'var1': .3, 'var2': 0.4})
```

More details can be found in this [tutorial notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/SheffieldML/GPyOpt/blob/master/manual/GPyOpt_context.ipynb) about contextual optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the `partial` function from the [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) standard library.  It allows you to partially specify a function, so for example:

```
import GPyOpt
import numpy as np
from functools import partial


def f(x, y=0):
    return np.sin(x - y)


objective = partial(f, y=2)
space = [{'name': 'x', 'type': 'continuous', 'domain': (-5, 5)}]

opt = GPyOpt.methods.BayesianOptimization(
    objective, domain=space
)
```

Comment: Definitely a cleaner workaround than what i was doing, but i still think there has to be a way to directly specify this in the `GPyOpt` object (fixing arguments seems way too important to require an external module)

Comment: You could also simply add a variable of type `discrete` to your space, like so: `{'name': 'y', 'type': 'discrete', 'domain': (2,)}`

Comment: That would work in this specific example, but e.g. if a function takes a string as argument this won't work. Of course you could then encode the string as integer, but that's again very messy.